# Can we create CRUD web apps using next.js, mongodb and netlify?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, next.js, crud, netlify

I want to create a CRUD web app using next.js with a mongodb database which is then hosted on netlify.

Can we do that???

Or, if that's not possible, do the three things I mentioned (next.js, mongodb, netlify) have an alternative that will make it possible?

Or, if that doesn't work either, is there a solution for me to be able to create CRUD web apps using javascript which are then hosted on netlify?

I have tried looking through all the templates on netlify and found no template for building CRUD web apps using next.js and mongodb.

Maybe I missed.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - You can. Please see this exhaustive tutorial from Mongodb.
https://www.mongodb.com/developer/languages/javascript/developing-web-application-netlify-serverless-functions-mongodb/

It requires the use of `netlify serverless functions`.

Whilst this example does not include next.js, it provides html and javascript examples that can easily be adapted to any front end framework.